# Exception in serialize with transient field

Tags: java, serialization

I had some class which is used for storing state of the application. I need to serialize and deserialize it in/from file. It worked without problem. Now I added a new transient field to it, and, of cource, I coldn't deserialize my old files. I deleted this new transient field in order to have got ability to open old files, but I couldn't do it again! I got the following exception:

com.qqer.fuzzy.app.ApplicationCurrentState; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6313827182653283573, local class serialVersionUID = 1

How can I fix it? I thought that I could just delete all new fields and all will be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of your serialVersionUID static field from 1 to 6313827182653283573, since that's the value it had when you serialized the object.

This will make it possible to deserialize the object, provided the class still has the exact same non-transient fields as it had when serializing it (which could not be true, since you introduced or changed the serialVersionUID field since then and forgot about it).

Comment: It doesn't have to have 'exactly the same non-transient fields', but there are other constraints. See the Object Serialization Specification, Object Versioning chapter. Introduction of the serialVersionUID member has nothing to do with it, as it's static.

Comment: It has to do with it, since the exception says that the local class has a serial version UID of 1, and that the serialized object has a serial version UID of 6313827182653283573.

Comment: How exactly does the fact that he introduced or changed the serialVersionUID field prove that his non-transient fields have also changed? A. It doesn't.

Comment: Hence the usage of "could not be true" instead of "is not true". The OP thought he came back to the exact same code as before, and it was obviously not the case.

Comment: Aha, so you really meant 'could be untrue'?

Answer (score 0):

you wil help  `serialver` set new version to all old classes, and all will be OK